# Is it correct that a sphere of water the size of Venus's orbit would instantly be a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, estimation, density

Let's say I have a genie and wish for a sphere of water at earth density the size of Venus' orbit - would it be instantly indistinguishable from a supermassive black hole due to the schwarzchild radius exceeding the volume at normal density?

Would it also outweigh Sagittarius A* at 150 million Suns?

I've taken the [Schwarzchild radius formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius), the density formula, and solved for r with the density of 1000 kg/m^3

Apologies, I don't know how to do formula in stack overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can super massive black holes have a lower density than water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5888/)

Comment: Also see [Can I eat myself into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415094/) which despite the odd title does calculate the size of a black hole with the density of water.

Comment: I believe the mass of your sphere of water would be about 2.1 million Suns, which is about half of the mass of Sgr A*.